# Adjusting Height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to adjust the **height** of a `UITableViewCell` to have multiple lines based on the text that is stored within an `NSString` - the contents of the `NSString` changes a number of times and therefore I cannot predefine the cell's **height**.

I have attempted the following however, as you can view from the images attached, this code yields a strange result in which the cell is too big:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    cell.textLabel.text = tableString;

    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);

    if ([termDefintion length] > 0)
        labelSize = [tableString sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 800) lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return labelSize.height;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

`tableString` is the NSString in which its content changes a number of times. Here are two screenshots, as you can see there's too much space above and below - http://bramhall.me/cell-1.png & http://bramhall.me/cell-2.png

Is there a more efficient means of accomplishing the correct result?

Comment: This might helps you: [DynamicHeights](https://github.com/lbj96347/DynamicHeights)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a frustrating thing, but it's definitely doable. There are several ways to do this, but the way I have chosen as my default method is to set it up in the following way:

1. Create all of my cells in code. This gives me the benefit of having more explicit control over everything. This is not necessarily **better**, but I like it better because it makes the entire process more intuitive to me.
2. Create a pair of methods like this (I can't get the formatting right, but the first method is a **CLASS** method and the second method is an **INSTANCE** method):

   - (CGFloat)heightNeededForObject:(id)objectUsedToConfigureCell;
   - (void)configureForObject:(id)objectUsedToConfigureCell;
3. Create private class methods that return values that I want for spacing, font size, etc.

Once all of that is done, the code in the `UITableViewController` becomes trivial. Basically, you get the data you need for configuration and pass it to the cell, asking it for the height that's needed or asking it to configure itself for the data.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
// UITableViewController
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PFObject *item = self.items[indexPath.row];
    return [ItemTableViewCell heightNeededForItem:item];
}
- (ItemTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ItemTableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *item           = self.items[indexPath.row];
    [cell configureForItem:item];
    return cell;
}


// UITableViewCell Subclass

// Header file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ItemTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

}

#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark - Public Class Methods
+ (CGFloat)heightNeededForItem:(PFObject *)item;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Public Instance Methods
- (void)configureForItem:(PFObject *)item;

@end

// Implementation file
// Header import
#import "ItemTableViewCell.h"

@interface ItemTableViewCell () {

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Controls
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *detailLabel;

@end
@implementation ItemTableViewCell

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Initialization
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [self setupUserInterface];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Public Class Methods
+ (CGFloat)heightNeededForItem:(PFObject *)item {
    NSString *detailString = item[@"property"];
    CGFloat availableWidth = // perhaps just the screen width; maybe more advanced logic here (e.g., if using cell accessories)

    UIFont *detailFont     = [self detailLabelFont];
    CGSize detailSize      = [detailString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(availableWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: detailFont}
                                                        context:nil].size;

    return [self topBottomMargin] + detailSize.height + [self topBottomMargin];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - "Methodized" Class Properties
+ (CGFloat)leftRightMargin {
    return 16.0f;
}
+ (CGFloat)detailLabelFontSize {
    if (IS_IPHONE_4 || IS_IPHONE_5) {
        return 14.0f;
    } else if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
        return 17.0f;
    } else if (IS_IPHONE_6PLUS) {
        return 20.0f;
    } else {
        return 24.0f;
    }
}
+ (CGFloat)topBottomMargin {
    return 16.0f;
}
+ (UIFont *)detailLabelFont {
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[self detailLabelFontSize]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Public Instance Methods
- (void)configureForItem:(PFObject *)item {
    // This could be very advanced...
    self.detailLabel.text = item[@"property"];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UI Setup
- (void)setupUserInterface {
    [self createControls];
    [self setupControls];
    [self layoutControls];
}
- (void)createControls {
    self.detailLabel    = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}
- (void)setupControls {        
    self.detailLabel.font   = [ItemTableViewCell detailLabelFont];
    // This is necessary for a pure auto layout scenario
    [self.detailLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}
- (void)layoutControls {
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.detailLabel];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(margin)-[label]-(margin)-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:@{@"margin"    : @([ItemTableViewCell leftRightMargin])}
                                                                               views:@{@"label"     : self.detailLabel}]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(margin)-[detail]-(margin)-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:@{@"margin"    : @([ItemTableViewCell topBottomMargin])}
                                                                               views:@{@"detail"    : self.detailLabel}]];
}
@end
```

FYI: The `IS_IPHONE_4`, `IS_IPHONE_5`, `IS_IPHONE_6`, `IS_IPHONE_6PLUS` are macros defined in a singleton helper class.

I hope this code makes sense. I actually pared down a working `UITableViewCell` subclass that I've got that has 2 labels (main and detail), but I figured it would be a better teaching tool to make it simpler. You can make the cell itself arbitrarily complex, and I've done so. You can end up with multiple labels/views in any configuration, and this setup allows the cell to handle all of its layout and configuration.

I've even used this approach to figure out the biggest height needed for a particular data set and then used that for all cells for consistency (rather than having each cell have a different height, which can look bad in some cases). You have to be careful with that, though, as iterating the data set in `-tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath:` would create a lot of unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 0):

Add Constraints to your Label in Storyboard and

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([TypeOfCell[indexPath.row] isEqualToString: @"Checklist"]) {
        if(!self.uitableviewcell){
            self. self.uitableviewcell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell identifies "];
        }

        //Configure the cell
        [cell.lblName setText:[names  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16]];
        //Layout the cell
        [self.cell layoutIfNeeded];
        //Get the height for the cell
        CGFloat heightTask = [self.checklistView.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

        return heightTask + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”

Comment: He is not using Autolayout. Make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

You approach to calculate height is wrong because you set your textlable font size to 16 in cellForRowAtIndexPath methods, and you calculate cell height using the font size 14. This is first notable issue. And another one is the width used to calculate height. That's why your height calculation is being wrong.

See below code, that's help you to calculate exact height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(cell.textLabel.frame.size.width,9999);
       CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];

       return MAX(set default cell height if needed, expectedLabelSize.height + (some padding if you want to add));   
}
```

If you have any trouble, let me know....